# Mixing matrix in particle physics

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, beyond-the-standard-model

It is familiar for us that the diagonalization of a mixing matrix which is written in the neutral basis gives the masses of the neutral particles.

If I construct a mixing matrix which is written in the basis ($X_1, X_2, X_3$) and ($N_1, N_2, N_3$) where $X_i (i=1,2,3)$ are charged particles while $N_i (i=1,2,3)$ are neutral. This mixing matrix has any physical sense?

Comment: The [PMNS matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PMNS_matrix) in SM neutrino physics connects charged lepton mass eigenstates to neutral neutrino mass eigenstates  and Ws. It is not a mass matrix, but a *coupling mixing matrix*. Is that what you might have in mind?

Comment: Actually, I have developed a lagrangian in a model beyond the standard model, and I found some terms represent the coupling between charged and neutral leptons as (E^-. Neutrino) where E^- is a charged lepton. and I wanted to know if it's okay to find those terms or its wrong.

Comment: Looks like they violate electric charge?

Comment: I found many terms represent couplings between charged and neutral leptons as (E^-. Beta^0) and (beta^+. Neutrino) and many others I don't understand how can I deal with them.  Are those forbidden terms?

Comment: Yes, they are., unless there also is a W there.

Comment: Okay professor, I will re calculate and see how to make them equal to zero,. Thank you so much for your helpful answers

Comment: Maybe i can add a symmetry to Lagrangian to can cancel those terms ? but i am wondering which symmetry i can add?

Comment: What do you mean by diagonalization of a mixing matrix? We usually diagonalize the mass matrices. @Narmine

Comment: Yes, you're right but I asked a question about what i will get if I diagonlize a mixing matrix.